# Count/ Group BY

Tags: sql-server-2008, count, group-by

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
        CONVERT(varchar(20),GetDate(),103) as 'Today''s Date'
        ,(D.Forename + ' ' + D.Surname) as 'Driver Name'
        ,V.Registration as 'Allocated Truck Reg'
        ,R.CollectionCompanyTown as 'Collection Location'
        ,R.DeliveryCompanyTown as 'Delivery Location'
        ,R.[Collection Date]
        ,R.[Delivery Date]
        ,R.[Fee Charge] as 'Revenue'
        ,R.Quantity
        ,R.ReservationsID
        ,C.[Trading Name] as 'Customer'
        ,Count([Customers Order Ref]) as count
        ,R.[Customers Order Ref]

FROM
        tblReservation R
        --LEFT JOIN tblDeliveryStages ds ON ds.ReservationsID = R.ReservationsID
        LEFT JOIN tblDriver D ON D.DriverID = R.DriverID
        LEFT JOIN tblVehicle V ON V.VehicleID = R.VehicleID
        LEFT JOIN tblCustomer C ON C.CustomerID = R.CustomerID
        LEFT JOIN tblReservationItems RI on RI.ReservationsID = r.ReservationsID and RI.Deleted != 1
        LEFT JOIN tblManifestReservation MR ON MR.ReservationsID = R.ReservationsID
        LEFT JOIN tblLoadManifest LM ON LM.LoadManifestID = MR .LoadManifestID




GROUP BY
        R.[Customers Order Ref]
        ,R.ReservationsID
        ,D.Forename 
        ,D.Surname
        ,V.Registration
        ,R.CollectionCompanyTown 
        ,R.DeliveryCompanyTown
        ,R.[Collection Date]
        ,R.[Delivery Date]
        ,R.[Fee Charge] 
        ,R.Quantity
        ,R.[Customers Order Ref]
        ,C.[Trading Name]


ORDER BY ReservationsID desc
```

The two main parts are the reservationsID and the Customers Order Ref. ReservationsID will always be unique, customers order ref will not, some reservations will share the same customers order ref.

I am trying to get a count of how many reservations share the customers order ref but the current count field just returns the below:

[image: Data returned]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [windowed variant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) of `COUNT()` and completely remove the `GROUP BY` clause. Something like:

```
Count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY [Customers Order Ref])
```

If I've understood what you're asking for correctly.